# Fedex Shipping Labels API not sending Address 2

Tags: php, api, soap, wsdl, fedex

THE SOAP REQUEST AS SENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:ProcessShipmentRequest>
      <ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <ns1:UserCredential>
          <ns1:Key>kQyj3MtQGLJ3ZYWG</ns1:Key>
          <ns1:Password>66ywMwyasljK5uRkaNENRZCZW</ns1:Password>
        </ns1:UserCredential>
      </ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <ns1:ClientDetail>
        <ns1:AccountNumber>510087682</ns1:AccountNumber>
        <ns1:MeterNumber>100154483</ns1:MeterNumber>
      </ns1:ClientDetail>
      <ns1:TransactionDetail>
        <ns1:CustomerTransactionId>*** Express Domestic Shipping Request v12 using PHP ***</ns1:CustomerTransactionId>
      </ns1:TransactionDetail>
      <ns1:Version>
        <ns1:ServiceId>ship</ns1:ServiceId>
        <ns1:Major>12</ns1:Major>
        <ns1:Intermediate>1</ns1:Intermediate>
        <ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor>
      </ns1:Version>
      <ns1:RequestedShipment>
        <ns1:ShipTimestamp>2013-03-25T14:33:08+00:00</ns1:ShipTimestamp>
        <ns1:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns1:DropoffType>
        <ns1:ServiceType>FEDEX_GROUND</ns1:ServiceType>
        <ns1:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns1:PackagingType>
        <ns1:TotalWeight>
          <ns1:Units>LB</ns1:Units>
          <ns1:Value>17.22</ns1:Value>
        </ns1:TotalWeight>
        <ns1:Shipper>
          <ns1:Contact>
            <ns1:PersonName>Shipping Department</ns1:PersonName>
            <ns1:CompanyName>Big Dog Treestands</ns1:CompanyName>
            <ns1:PhoneNumber>3092636800</ns1:PhoneNumber>
          </ns1:Contact>
          <ns1:Address>
            <ns1:StreetLines>120 E. Detroit Parkway</ns1:StreetLines>
            <ns1:City>Morton</ns1:City>
            <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>IL</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <ns1:PostalCode>61550</ns1:PostalCode>
            <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
          </ns1:Address>
        </ns1:Shipper>
        <ns1:Recipient>
          <ns1:Contact>
            <ns1:PersonName>David Sinc</ns1:PersonName>
            <ns1:CompanyName>TEST COMPANY</ns1:CompanyName>
            <ns1:PhoneNumber>3093701229</ns1:PhoneNumber>
          </ns1:Contact>
          <ns1:Address>
            <ns1:StreetLines>1202 Chalet Ln</ns1:StreetLines>
            <ns1:StreetLines>HIDDLY- Test Account</ns1:StreetLines>
            <ns1:City>PEORIA</ns1:City>
            <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>IL</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <ns1:PostalCode>61614</ns1:PostalCode>
            <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
            <ns1:Residential>false</ns1:Residential>
          </ns1:Address>
        </ns1:Recipient>
        <ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
          <ns1:PaymentType>SENDER</ns1:PaymentType>
          <ns1:Payor>
            <ns1:ResponsibleParty>
              <ns1:AccountNumber>510087682</ns1:AccountNumber>
              <ns1:Contact/>
              <ns1:Address>
                <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
              </ns1:Address>
            </ns1:ResponsibleParty>
          </ns1:Payor>
        </ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
        <ns1:LabelSpecification>
          <ns1:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</ns1:LabelFormatType>
          <ns1:ImageType>PDF</ns1:ImageType>
          <ns1:LabelStockType>PAPER_8.5X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL</ns1:LabelStockType>
        </ns1:LabelSpecification>
        <ns1:RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</ns1:RateRequestTypes>
        <ns1:PackageCount>1</ns1:PackageCount>
        <ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
          <ns1:SequenceNumber>1</ns1:SequenceNumber>
          <ns1:GroupPackageCount>1</ns1:GroupPackageCount>
          <ns1:Weight>
            <ns1:Units>LB</ns1:Units>
            <ns1:Value>17.22</ns1:Value>
          </ns1:Weight>
        </ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
      </ns1:RequestedShipment>
    </ns1:ProcessShipmentRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Fedex APpplication Code

```
<?php

// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Version 12.0.0

require_once('library/fedex-common.php5');


//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "http://bigdog.webdesign309.com/wp-content/themes/bigdogtreestands-new/woocommerce/emails/ShipWebServiceClient/wsdl/ShipService_v12.wsdl";
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
define('SHIP_LABEL', $uploads['basedir'].'/shippinglabels/shipexpresslabel'.str_replace('#','',$order->get_order_number()).'.pdf');  // PNG label file. Change to file-extension .pdf for creating a PDF label (e.g. shiplabel.pdf)

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information


$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => '*** Express Domestic Shipping Request v12 using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'ship', 
    'Major' => '12', 
    'Intermediate' => '1', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$ships = $order->get_shipping_method();
$shippingType = "FEDEX_GROUND";
if($ships == "Fedex  Ground"){
    $shippingType = "FEDEX_GROUND"; 
}
else if( $ships == "Fedex  2 Day"){
    $shippingType = "FEDEX_2_DAY"; 
}
else if($ships == "Fedex  Standard Overnight"){
    $shippingType = "STANDARD_OVERNIGHT"; 
}
else if($ships == "Fedex  Home Delivery"){
         $shippingType = "GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY"; 
}
function totalOrderWeight($orders) {
    $totalWeight = 0;
    $items = $orders->get_items();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $product = get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        $quantity = intval( $item['qty'] );
        $totalWeight +=  $product->get_weight() * $quantity;
    }
    return $totalWeight;
}

$request['RequestedShipment'] = array(
    'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
    'DropoffType' => 'REGULAR_PICKUP', // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, DROP_BOX, BUSINESS_SERVICE_CENTER and STATION
    'ServiceType' => $shippingType, // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
    'PackagingType' => 'YOUR_PACKAGING', // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
    'TotalWeight' => array('Value' => totalOrderWeight($order), 'Units' => 'LB'), // valid values LB and KG
    'Shipper' => addShipper(),
    'Recipient' => addRecipient($order),
    'ShippingChargesPayment' => addShippingChargesPayment(),
    'LabelSpecification' => addLabelSpecification(),  
    'RateRequestTypes' => array('ACCOUNT'), // valid values ACCOUNT and LIST
    'PackageCount' => 1,
    'RequestedPackageLineItems' => array(
        '0' => addPackageLineItem1(totalOrderWeight($order))
    )
);
try 
{
    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint'))
    {
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
    }

    $response = $client->processShipment($request);  // FedEx web service invocation

    if ($response->HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response->HighestSeverity != 'ERROR')
    {       
        printSuccess($client, $response);


        $label = 
        // Create PNG or PDF label
        // Set LabelSpecification.ImageType to 'PDF' or 'PNG for generating a PDF or a PNG label       
        $fp = fopen(SHIP_LABEL, 'wb');   
        fwrite($fp, $response->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->Label->Parts->Image); //Create PNG or PDF file
        fclose($fp);
     //   echo '<a href="'.$uploads['url'].'/shippinglabels/shipexpresslabel'.str_replace('#','',$order->get_order_number()).'.pdf">Click Here to Download Shipping Label</a> was generated.';
    }
    else
    {
        printError($client, $response);
    }

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    printFault($exception, $client);
}
function addShipper(){
    $shipper = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Shipping Department',
            'CompanyName' => 'Big Dog Treestands',
            'PhoneNumber' => '3092636800'),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('120 E. Detroit Parkway'),
            'City' => 'Morton',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'IL',
            'PostalCode' => '61550',
            'CountryCode' => 'US')
    );
    return $shipper;
}
function addRecipient($orders){ 
    $residential = get_post_meta($orders->get_order_number(), '_residential-indicator');
/*  echo 'Shipping Address 2:'.$orders->shipping_address_2;
    echo 'Shipping Address 1:'.$orders->shipping_address_1; */
    if($orders->shipping_address_2){
        $addressArray = array($orders->shipping_address_1, $orders->shipping_address_2); 
/*      echo 'Shipping Address 2'; */
            /* $addressArray =array('StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1' => $orders->shipping_address_1, 'Address Line 2' => $orders->shipping_address_2)); */
    }
    else{
        $addressArray = array($orders->shipping_address_1);
/*      echo 'Shipping Address 1'; */
    }
    $joy = false;
    if($residential == 1){
        $joy = true;
    }
    else{
        $joy = false;
    }
            $recipient = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' =>  $orders->billing_first_name . ' ' . $orders->billing_last_name,
            'CompanyName' => $orders->shipping_company,
            'PhoneNumber' => $orders->billing_phone),
/*          'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' =>  array($orders->shipping_address_1, $orders->shipping_address_2),
            'City' => $orders->shipping_city,
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => $orders->shipping_state,
            'PostalCode' => $orders->shipping_postcode,
            'CountryCode' => 'US',
            'Residential' => $joy) */
        'Address' => array(
             'StreetLines'=>array($orders->shipping_address_1, $orders->shipping_address_2),
            //array(utf8_encode($orders->shipping_address_1), utf8_encode($orders->shipping_address_2)),
            'City' => $orders->shipping_city,
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => $orders->shipping_state,
            'PostalCode' => $orders->shipping_postcode,
            'CountryCode' => 'US',
            'Residential' => $joy)
    );
    return $recipient;                                      
}
function addShippingChargesPayment(){
    $shippingChargesPayment = array('PaymentType' => 'SENDER',
        'Payor' => array(
        'ResponsibleParty' => array(
            'AccountNumber' => getProperty('billaccount'),
            'Contact' => null,
            'Address' => array('CountryCode' => 'US'))));
    return $shippingChargesPayment;
}
function addLabelSpecification(){
    $labelSpecification = array(
        'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D', // valid values COMMON2D, LABEL_DATA_ONLY
        'ImageType' => 'PDF',  // valid values DPL, EPL2, PDF, ZPLII and PNG
        'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_8.5X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL');
    return $labelSpecification;
}
function addPackageLineItem1($weight){
    $packageLineItem = array(
        'SequenceNumber'=>1,
        'GroupPackageCount'=>1,
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => $weight,
            'Units' => 'LB')

    );
    return $packageLineItem;
}

?>
```

It returns this http://bigdog.webdesign309.com/assets/shippinglabels/shipexpresslabel1303.pdf

I have tried everything even calling fedex and they say that they provide no support for this issue as the code is a convenience rather than a service. If anyone can shed some light on this most puzzling issue as to why the second address field never shows up that would be great.
Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: If you have any ideas at all as to what the issue is please post anything. I am up for any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean that you are having trouble with the recipient address 2 not showing on the label? Your .PDF file link is broken so I can't see it.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else comes across this problem, note that FedEx's test labels from their staging environment do not appear to ever include the second address line.

All of my test labels did NOT have a second address line, but as soon as I switched to the production server, the labels had the second line.

Comment: I'm assuming this is because they are reserving that space for the "Test Label- Do Not Ship" Disclaimer spot? This answered my question however, because it does work for the origin address on test.

Answer (score 0):

It should have multiple address lines as your XML looks valid. FedEx support should be able to provide assistance based on the SOAP request/response, but will not provide assistance with your PHP coding.

Answer (score 0):

according to the Ship Service Docs, you only have two address lines, I solved like this:

```
'Address' => array(
        'StreetLines' => array($array_recipient["address_1"],$array_recipient["address_2"]),
        'City' => $array_recipient["City"],
        'StateOrProvinceCode' => $array_recipient["StateOrProvinceCode"],
        'PostalCode' => $array_recipient["PostalCode"],
        'CountryCode' => 'MX',
        'Residential' => true
    )
```

in case you need more "space" you can use CUSTOMER_REFERENCE (rigth after dimensions):

```
$packageLineItem = array(
    'SequenceNumber'=>1,
    'GroupPackageCount'=>1,
    'Weight' => array(
        'Value' => $dimension_array["weight"],
        'Units' => 'KG'
    ),
    'Dimensions' => array(
        'Length' => $dimension_array["length"],
        'Width' => $dimension_array["width"],
        'Height' => $dimension_array["height"],
        'Units' => 'CM'
    ),
    'CustomerReferences' => array(
    'CustomerReferenceType' => 'CUSTOMER_REFERENCE',
    'Value' => $dimension_array["more_references"]
    ),
```

If you make the request in Test Enviroment, the second address will not show, but after to production, the second address will shown.

Hope this help you.